# How to calculate the smallest gap between two or more non zero elements in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4  
0  1  2  3  0  
1  4  0  3  0  
2  2  0  0  3  
3  0  3  0  3
```

Then I want to add another column such that it will display the smallest gap( gap is the number of zero elements between two non zero element). If there is no such gap the output will be 0. The column will look like:

```
  Cnew  
0 0  
1 1  
2 2  
3 1
```

First row has no gap. Second row has a single gap between 4 and 3. Third row has two gaps between 2 and 3. Fourth row has a gap between 3 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find non-zero locations with `np.where` and take the diff of those locations.  The maximum difference is one more than the gap.

```
[np.diff(np.where(x)[0]).max() - 1 for x in df.values]

[0, 1, 2, 1]
```

You can add this to a copy of `df` with `assign`

```
df.assign(Cnew=[np.diff(np.where(x)[0]).max() - 1 for x in df.values])

   C1  C2  C3  C4  Cnew
0   1   2   3   0     0
1   4   0   3   0     1
2   2   0   0   3     2
3   0   3   0   3     1
```

Or add the column in place

```
df['Cnew'] = [np.diff(np.where(x)[0]).max() - 1 for x in df.values]
df

   C1  C2  C3  C4  Cnew
0   1   2   3   0     0
1   4   0   3   0     1
2   2   0   0   3     2
3   0   3   0   3     1
```

---

To make this robust in the situations where there are one or zero non-zeros in a row, we can define a function to handle those cases

```
def biggest_gap(x):
    d = np.diff(np.where(x)[0])
    if bool(d.tolist()):
        return d.max() - 1
    else:
        return 0
```

then use it like this

```
[biggest_gap(x) for x in df.values]

[0, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Wow!   +1 nice, piRSquared

Comment: Thx @ScottBoston